# How can I view a route from a .kml file overlayed on an Ordnance Survey map?

Tags: maps, ordnance-survey

I am taking part in a 100K event later this year, and the organizers have made available a .kml file of the route downloadable from [here](https://www.wyevalleychallenge.com/the-challenge/the-route). This is great, but I want to view this route on a UK 1:25000 Ordnance Survey (OS) map, the kind that Bing Maps presents, when you choose Ordnance Survey as your display option. As is, I can only view the route in Google Maps which lacks much of the information than an OS map provides.

I can compare Google Maps displaying the .kml route side-by-side with Bing Maps displaying the OS map, but is there a way of pulling the .kml file into Bing Maps? Or is this functionality available elsewhere?

Comment: GPSBabel should be able to convert the kml to a standard gpx, which bing might be able to display

Answer (score 2):

I believe that what you are looking for is,

- [Gavin Brock's Ordnance Survey Map KML Overlays for the UK](http://www.brock-family.org/gavin/google-earth/osmaps.html)
- Same one found [here](http://www.gelib.com/ordnace-survey-maps.htm).
- [The Charles Close Society for the Study of Ordnance Survey Maps](https://www.charlesclosesociety.org/KMLFILE)

Any of these should put an Ordnace Survey overlay into Google Earth and then you could combine that with the .kml file you already have.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to GPX eith with Chris h's suggestion above or http://gpx2kml.com/ will convert Kml to gpx and back.

I really like Viewranger, is a great phone app that will allow you to have GPS navigation with your route overlayed onto an OS map. I'm guessing that you're after a more desktop approach though.